# How to make a value appear for another id after a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hail! I'm trying change the price of a thing by the name of choice. I tried a lot of things like change my function, put anothers parameters but I did stuck.

HTML:

```
<div id="options" class="btn-group" role="group">
   {% for option in product.options %}
      <button type="button" class="option-btn btn btn-light"
         data-price="{{ option.price }}">{{ option.name }}</button>
   {% endfor %}
</div>

<div id="price" class="price"></div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Set default price
   var first_option = $('#options button').first();
   first_option.addClass('active');
   $('#price').text(first_option.data('price'));

   // Call newsletter modal
   $('#newsletter').modal();

   // Activate change price
   $('.option-btn').on('click', function (e) {
       changePrice(e);                
   });
})

var changePrice = function (e) {
   // Change active classes
   $('.option-btn').removeClass('active');
   $(e.target).addClass('active');
}
```

The goal is, by clicking on the product choice, the price of it change according to the selected choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this listener

```
$('#options').on('click', '.option-btn', function() {
   $('#options .option-btn').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   const value = $(this).data('price');
   $('#price').text(value);
});
```

Comment: I am glad to help you. If it is answer for your question please mark it as answered.